# Enhance performance of a mobile application in high Jitter Data Network

Tags: c#, android, .net, soap

There is an android application which is connected to a server and fetch some data using SOAP protocol. The application cannot load the data in a high Jitter data network. It means if the Jitter of the network is high, the application will not work well, and will not load the data.

The question is what is the best practice to solve the issue some how the application works in a high latency data network? Is there any config should I have done in client-side (android) or server-side (SOAP, .NET)?

I should mention that here **Jitter** means *In networking, in particular IP networks such as the Internet, jitter can refer to the variation (statistical dispersion) in the delay of the packets.*[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter)